# Add a service to Android in React Native project

Tags: android, react-native, service

I have a React Native project, I would like to add a service to the Android build.

I have added the service to the application in the `AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
      <service android:name=".app.MessengerService"
           android:process=":remote" />
```

And created a file called `MessengerService.java` that just has a sample service from the android studio support site (shortened for brevity):

```
public class MessengerService extends Service {
    /** For showing and hiding our notification. */
    NotificationManager mNM;
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I try to build the project I get an error like this:

```
/android/app/src/main/java/com/family_insites/MessengerService.java:1: 
error: cannot find symbol
public class MessengerService extends Service {
                                      ^
symbol: class Service
```

I haven't done much on the android studio side of things, so I am wondering if I have taken the wrong approach here or if there is a better way to do this?  Ultimately the end goal is to set up a Device Policy Management service, but initially I am just trying to get a basic service started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to error, you are not importing Service class.

```
/android/app/src/main/java/com/family_insites/MessengerService.java:1: 
public class MessengerService extends Service {
//...
}
```

Correct version:

```
package your.domain;

import android.app.Service;

public class MessengerService extends Service {
    //...
}
```